# Objective-C error: No visible @interface declares the selector

Tags: objective-c, cordova

I have next to no knowledge of Objective-C, but I'm using Cordova (PhoneGap) to create a web app and needed to manipulate the headers sent by their InAppBrowser plugin.

I have managed to get custom headers to send with the request, I changed the NSURLRequest to a NSMutableURLRequest and then set a custom header like this:

```
NSMutableURLRequest* request = [NSMutableURLRequest requestWithURL:url]; 
[request setValue:@"test" forHTTPHeaderField:@"Accept-Encoding"];
```

My next problem was passing the headers from the javascript. I added an additional option to the parameters. The parameters need to be passed along between several functions (or methods?) before they get to the place where I can manipulate the headers. I've managed to pass them through several functions, and NSLog is still showing me the correct value that I sent from my javascript, but I've fallen at the final hurdle. I can't pass an additional parameter to my final function!

I have this bit of code here:

```
[self.inAppBrowserViewController navigateTo:url withHeaders:headers ];
```

Which calls the navigateTo function that is defined like this:

```
- (void)navigateTo:(NSURL*)url withHeaders:(NSString*)headers
{
    NSMutableURLRequest* request = [NSMutableURLRequest requestWithURL:url];
    [request setValue:@"test" forHTTPHeaderField:@"Accept-Encoding"];
    if (_userAgentLockToken != 0) {
        [self.webView loadRequest:request];
    } else {
        [CDVUserAgentUtil acquireLock:^(NSInteger lockToken) {
            _userAgentLockToken = lockToken;
            [CDVUserAgentUtil setUserAgent:_userAgent lockToken:lockToken];
            [self.webView loadRequest:request];
        }];
    }
}
```

The problem I have is that the line that calls navigateTo is giving me the error: "CordovaLib/Classes/CDVInAppBrowser.m:149:6: No visible @interface for 'CDVInAppBrowserViewController' declares the selector 'navigateTo:withHeaders:'"

Comment: You get this error usually if you misspelled a method name.

Comment: Triple checked the speeling, all seems fine.

Comment: `- (void)navigateTo:(NSURL*)url withHeaders:(NSString*)headers` this method is declared in `CDVInAppBrowserViewController.h` and defined its implementation in `CDVInAppBrowserViewController.m` ? and self.inAppBrowserViewController is an instance of `CDVInAppBrowserViewController` class?

Comment: No. Didn't realise I had to change something in the .h file! I changed the navigateTo line to `- (void)navigateTo:(NSURL*)url (NSString*)headers;` but this now says "Expected ; after method prototype"

Comment: yeah line ends with `;` you have to add that

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Declare the method in CDVInAppBrowserViewController.h as

```
- (void)navigateTo:(NSURL*)url withHeaders:(NSString*)headers;
```